# Error using posdm.exe from POS for .NET on Windows 10

Tags: pointofservice

On Windows 10 running a simple `posdm.exe` from the command line gives the error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Point Of Service>posdm listsos
POSDM: Error executing WMI query: 'SELECT * from ServiceObject ', res=c0c02402: 0xC0C02402
```

I am unable to find anything online about this. I have installed Microsoft POS for .NET version 1.12. Is this a compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is just the error you receive when you use this old version on Windows 10. Upgrading to version 1.14.1 fixed the error for me. Unfortunately I will still need to test things on 1.12 for compatibility checking so will have to use a virtual machine for that.